# Homebrew brew doctor warning about /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework, even with brew's Python installed

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, homebrew, brew-doctor

When I ran **Homebrew's** `brew doctor` (Mac OS X 10.9.2), I get the following warning message:

> Warning: Python is installed at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework
>
> Homebrew only supports building against the System-provided Python or
>   a brewed Python. In particular, Pythons installed to /Library can
>   interfere with other software installs.

Therefore, I ran `brew install` and followed the steps provided in the installation's caveats output to install Homebrew's version of **Python**. Running `which python` confirms that Homebrew's version of it is indeed at the top of my *PATH*. Output is `/usr/local/bin/python`.

Despite all this, when I rerun `brew doctor`, I am still getting the *same warning message*. How do I suppress this warning? Do I need to delete the /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework directory from my computer? Am I just supposed to ignore it? Is there a different application on my computer that may be causing this warning to emit?

Note that I don't have any applications in particular that are running into errors due to this warning from `brew doctor`. Also note that this warning message didn't always print out when I ran `brew doctor`, it was something that started to appear recently. Also, I am using Python 2.7 on my computer, trying to stay away from Python 3.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I had the same problem. When I upgraded python3 through Homebrew, I started getting this:

```
-bash: python3: command not found
```

I had the same conflict with Python somehow being installed in `/Library/Framework/Python.framework`. I just did a `brew link overwrite` and everything is working fine now. There is some info about what to do with the Python version in the `/Library/Framework/Python.framework` [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/27146).

I guess you could try deleting that version as the link suggests, just make sure that version isn't being used. When I got into the Python.framework directory I was seeing some EPD version of Python, which I think is Enthought. You could delete it, but I if it isn't causing you any problems besides the unsightly Homebrew warning message, then I think you should just ignore it for now.

Update:

I did delete the Python.framework directory which, through some poking around inside that directory, I started seeing a few old versions of Python that I didn't install with Homebrew. One was from Enthought, and another was a distribution of Python3.3. I think some of these installs in the Framework directory are user installs. I installed R on my system, and there is also an R.framework directory, so I think most of these are user installs. After I deleted the directory, I just had to call brew prune to remove the old symlinks. I checked both brew versions of python 2.7.6 and 3.3.4, and they seem to be in good working order with all of my installed packages. I guess I leave the decision to remove that directory, or python version, to your discretion.

Comment: on my el capitan laptop, the python versions at `/Library/...` are the ones actually being used and are symlinked from `/usr/local/bin/python` and `/usr/local/bin/python3`. So be sure to see how you're set up before just deleting them.

Comment: Where can I access this /Library directory?

Answer (score 37):

I also received this message.

Something, sometime installed

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework

on my machine (the folder date was about 4 years old).

I've chosen to remove it.

Please note that the Apple provided framework lives in

> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/

Answer (score 21):

per [this thread](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/27146), enter this command:

`sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework`

because there are multiple installations of Python on your computer, and this removes the one that may cause additional problems in the future.

Comment: A bit less drastic way would be to move the Python.framework directory to some other name, like Python.framework.old.  That way if you can put the directory back if someone goes wrong.

Comment: This is not a good solution, as the system level Python is used by many applications.

Comment: @jmcmahon443 This is not the system Python, it is the one you installed outside homebrew.

Answer (score 14):

You can use this solution as I've put below

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework

brew doctor 

brew prune

brew update
```

That combo fixed it for me, even thought this error usually doesn't cause any major problems its just was annoying me to see them pop up under brew doctor

Answer (score 2):

Removing directories manually can be a nightmare, but fortunately 'brew' can take care of that. Once you are done with the removal, put this:

```
brew doctor
```

The above command will list the broken system links. In order to get rid of these broken symlinks, put this:

```
brew prune
```

Check with 'brew doctor' once more to ensure no links are broken. Your system will then be ready to brew.

Comment: `brew prune` is now deprecated, `brew cleanup` should be used instead

Answer (score 0):

I had installed Python 3 from Homebrew and then another Python 3 directly from the Python website.

I deleted `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework`. I did not add any `PATH` or `PYTHONPATH` variables in `.bash_profile`. Then I checked the following in the shell:

```
~$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Feb  7 2017, 00:08:15)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> quit()

~$ python3
Python 3.6.4 (default, Mar  9 2018, 23:15:12)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> quit()

~$
```

In addition, I checked the following:

```
~$ whereis python
/usr/bin/python

~$ whereis python3

~$ which python
/usr/bin/python

~$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3

~$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip

~$ which pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3

~$ whereis pip

~$ whereis pip3
```

I was a bit worried that `whereis python3`, `whereis pip`, and `whereis pip3` returned nothing, but since there was no problem launching Python, I'd think it's safe to delete `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework`. Ask me again in a month.