# What is the safest way to removing Python framework files that are located in different place than Brew installs

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, brew-doctor

I want to remove a Python installed in location that brew complains about, when I run `brew doctor`

> **Warning:** Python is installed at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework

**What is the best way?**

**Here are more details / research:**

The message from the brew git [website](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Homebrew-and-Python):

> **Important:** If you choose to install a Python which isn't either of
>   these two (system Python or brewed Python), the Homebrew team can only
>   provide limited support.

**I want to make sure I am not missing anything before I remove the extra python libary.** 
Specifically, I want to remove the entire Python.framework, those files located here. 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/

I have Python 2.7.5 installed natively with Mavericks that I'll use instead - located in the path below. (The difference being -- I believe -- that its put in the **root  /System folder** instead of the **root  /Library folder**.) The good, native location is here:
`/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python`

and I already installed python 3.x with `brew install python3`, which put it here:

```
==> Summary
    /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.0  : 5076 files, 85M, built in 112 seconds
```

Can I just delete these files or are their consequences (beyond having to relink)?
`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/`

Here are steps to remove python from a [stackoverflow question in 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4/3819829#3819829) and a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22255579/homebrew-brew-doctor-warning-about-library-frameworks-python-framework-even-wi)

Is that approach still sound? Is there anything I should be aware of?

Comment: I had the native python on Mac OS, without removing which I installed python using brew and it created new symlinks and updated the hash for python too, works like a charm. If one isn't worried a lot about removing the older binaries, there isn't a necessity to remove them at all.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I'll self-answer. I went through steps and it's straight forward. Pycharms (the IDE I'm use) automatically found the new libraries too. Here are the steps I followed to remove the extra Python libraries on Mavericks that were not native to it and not installed by brew.

**Step 1:**
The native Python 2.7.x version lives here `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7` (or 2.6, etc), so you can remove any Python that got installed elsewhere.

`sudo rm -rf /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/`

Or, according to this [article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/good-clean-python-install), you should brew install both python 2.7 and python 3.x,
and avoid using system python in Mavericks.

**Step 2:**
Remove python in Applications directory (the one where all your apps are).

cd into folder `/Applications` and `ls | grep Python` to see what have.

Then remove:
`sudo rm -rf "Python 3.3"`

**Step 3:**

`>>> brew prune`

sample output:

> Pruned 0 dead formula Pruned 46 symbolic links from /usr/local

**Step 4:** Run steps recommended by `brew doctor`

`sudo brew link python3`

Sample output

> Linking /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.0... 19 symlinks created

Comment: You also need to find and delete any broken symlinks in `/usr/local/bin` that point to the removed `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework` directory

Comment: @mp3por - try `ls -ld /usr/local/bin| grep Python`

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4/3819829#3819829

Comment: what if there is no Python.framework in /Library/Frameworks/, but there is a folder named python in /Library? Can I remove this folder?

Comment: DO NOT DO THIS! This information may have been correct before, but it is dangerous to follow now. Your system needs the built-in Python to be where it expects it to be. So leave the system Python alone, and use Homebrew Python instead. See https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python.html