# Python not recognized on my computer but it says its installed

Tags: macos, python-2.7, python-3.x

I followed this post's advice and now I can no longer get python working on my computer. [What is the safest way to removing Python framework files that are located in different place than Brew installs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774529/what-is-the-safest-way-to-removing-python-framework-files-that-are-located-in-di?newreg=414ed222d2b84974a75562e5a14485e5)

When typing "brew search python" into the terminal it says both python and python3 are installed. However, my terminal doesn't recognize any python commands or let my reinstall python

the below is my bash profile

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.5
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH


# Setting PATH for Python 3.4
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

Comment: Try to use locate command from terminal and find where the python binary located at.. add that path to the .profile file.. http://osxdaily.com/2011/11/02/enable-and-use-the-locate-command-in-the-mac-os-x-terminal/

Comment: Or without having to make the `locate` database, you can try `which python`. What happens when you run `brew install python`; or did you not want to reinstall the homebrew Python?