# Which python am I using?

Tags: python, version, homebrew

Having trouble making sure I'm actually using the latest versions of Python even though they are already installed via homebrew.

```
$ brew upgrade python3
Error: python3 3.6.2 already installed
```

but:

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.0
```

same goes for python2:

```
$ brew upgrade python
Error: python2 2.7.13_1 already installed

$ python --version
Python 2.7.10`
```

Comment: I wouldnt worry too much about the minor version of your python installation

Comment: I'm having pip installation errors on language-check, I'm looking here and some of the answers mention fixes on newer minor versions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/urllib-and-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error#comment72358900_42334357

Comment: So I want to make sure I'm using the newer versions when I'm installing via pip

Comment: @kanjaklub, I don't have a Mac, but I'm betting you  have a PATH problem there.  Looks like you have both installed, but the one on the PATH is not what you want.  Does Mac have `locate`?  If so, try running `locate bin/python`, and see what it returns.

Comment: `brew` installs into `/usr/local/bin` by default. Your shell uses your `PATH` configuration to find binaries, it looks like you did not configure it to include `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: You can use the full path to the binary to force the issue: `/usr/local/bin/python3`.

Comment: Use `which` to tell you what binary was used when you just state the `python` or `python3` commands, e.g. `which python3`. If you use the `-a` command-line switch all binaries available via your `PATH` are listed: `which -a python3`.

Comment: `which -a python3` outputs `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3`

Comment: Here is my `$PATH`: `-bash: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin: No such file or directory`

Comment: Here is what I get with `locate bin/python`: `WARNING: The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist.
To create the database, run the following command:

  sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist

Please be aware that the database can take some time to generate; once
the database has been created, this message will no longer appear.`

Comment: plz update the python - plz do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I modified my $PATH: `sudo nano /etc/paths` so that `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin` was not being invoked. I made sure my paths were in the right order so that python looked for `/usr/local/bin/python3` and `/usr/local/bin/python2` first to force the issue.

However, `$ python3 --version` still returned 
`Python 3.6.0`, though brew says `python3 3.6.2 already installed`.

`brew doctor` to the rescue: homebrew recommended a couple things. python was incorrectly symlinked so I ran `brew --overwrite python3`. Finally, it diagnosed python coming from `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin`, so I `sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework`. Now python versions are correct.

[Homebrew brew doctor warning about /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework, even with brew's Python installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22255579/homebrew-brew-doctor-warning-about-library-frameworks-python-framework-even-wi)

Thank you everyone for your help.

Comment: plz update the python - plz do so

Answer (score 3):

```
❯ echo `which python`
```

If this doesn't print '/usr/local/bin/python' (where brew actually installs binaries), then there's something wrong with your $PATH (probably '/usr/local/bin' is not there or it's inserted after '/usr/bin', so the system default python is being run instead).

++ it seems that brew names its python2.7 as *python2* by default, and not as *python*, so you may also need to create a python2->python link in /usr/local/bin directory.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have separate environment variables set up for each?

I have found in the past that having multiple versions of python 2 for example, without all the environment variables, can get quite confusing!

You may find when typing python3, windows is only looking at python 3.0, unless you are in the python 3.6.2 directory.

Comment: plz update the python  - plz do  so